# Android WebView - Need to keep waiting till the URL is available

Tags: android, webview

I am new to Android app development, and I need to make a simple WebView application.  With my minimal knowledge and by referring articles over Internet, could do that and load the specified URL.

But my problem is that the URL may not be available all the time. URL is streamed from another device and thus, I need to keep my WebView waiting or keep refreshing till the URL is available.  Once the URL is accessible, need to get it loaded on WebView.

Can anyone please guide me on how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use WebView for waiting. Use simple HttpUrlConnection. There are a lot of example here on Stackoverflow hot to do so.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirements this will be implemented as below-

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView)

        // Initialize the WebView and load the URL.
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com")

        // Create a coroutine that will check the URL's availability.
        launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            // Check the URL's availability.
            while (!isURLAvailable("https://www.google.com")) {
                delay(1000)
            }

            // The URL is available, load it in the WebView.
            webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com")
        }
    }
```

Check the URL's availability

```
private fun isURLAvailable(url: String): Boolean {
        try {
            val connection = URL(url).openConnection()
            connection.connect()
            return true
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false
        }
    }
```

If the URL is not available after a certain amount of time, stop checking.

Comment: Hi @Vinay, thanks for the detailed update.  However, when I tried to implement this, came across a compilation error on `launch(Dispatchers.IO)` and based on some searching on Internet, I changed it to `GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO)`.

Anyhow, when I launch the application with  emulator, it loads the initial URL and after some time (assuming after the delay set), it crashes.